# ImageButton with PNG image with transparent background as background

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an Android application and I have created an ImageButton programatically:

```
int dps = 100;
final float scale = getActivity().getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int pixels = (int) (dps * scale + 0.5f);

ImageButton button = new ImageButton(getActivity());
button.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_start);
button.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams((int)(pixels * 1.24f), pixels));
button.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
layout.addView(button);
```

My problem is that I'm using an image with its background transparent but I see the image over a grey background.

**Is there any way to show only the image, not the grey background?**

Comment: @android:color/transparent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try with

`button.setBackgroundResource(0)`;

through xml should be `android:background="@null"`